# Why does TCP_INFO option on getsockopt() return contradicting values?

Tags: tcp, redhat, getsockopt

I do a

```
getsockopt(sfd, SOL_TCP, TCP_INFO, (void *)&info, (socklen_t *)&infoLen)
```

When I print the `tcpi_state` and `tcpi_ca_state` I get

```
tcpi_state = 7   (CLOSE)
tcpi_ca_state = 0  (OPEN)
```

The getsockopt with `SO_ERROR` returns no error (0).

What should I make of this ?

When I did a getpeername using the sfd, I got back "Transport endpoint not connected".

Is the tcp_info struct not dependable?

Comment: There is no contradiction here. `tcpi_ca_state` is the state of the congestion control automaton. It doesn't have anything to to with `tcpi_state`.

Comment: @EJP  So the connection is really closed ?